# ¿Cómo devolver correctamente valores de atributos en Java con este código?

Tags: java

He creado un nuevo paquete que se llama Coches y dentro de él tengo dos clases las cuales contiene:

1º

```
package coches;

public class coche {

    //Atributos
    private char color;
    private int matricula;
    private char tamaño;
    private char marca;
    private double version;

    //Métodos
    public char color (char x){
        color = x;
        return x;
    }
    public char matricula (char y){ 
        matricula = y;
        return y;
    }
    public char marca (char z){
        marca = z;
        return z;
    }
    public double version (double a){
        version = a;
        return a;
    }
}
```

2º Clase para el llamar al programa:

```
package coches;

public class programa {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //Llamo a la clase coche
        coche q;
        q = new coche();
        //Ejecuto sus métodos
        q.color(azul);
        q.marca(Ford);
        q.version(1,4);
        q.tamaño(mediano);

    }

}
```

Lo que quiero es que me devuelva 4 atributos del coche. La cosa es que no me funciona; no tengo idea de cómo visualizar estos atributos.

Comment: ésta pregunta tiene un voto (el mio) y como tantas otras tienen mas respuestas que votos, respuestas validadas pero sin puntacion ... sabeis que esta comunidad se basa en reputacion verdad?

Comment: @lois6b es comprensible porque la pregunta es bastante básica.. así que la gente no se interesará tanto en votarla útil.
Por la misma razón, la pregunta tiene varias respuestas rápidas ;)

Comment: Pero no me refiero solo a esta. a muchas en esta comunidad

Comment: Eso es verdad.. habrá que dar tiempo a que la gente se acostumbre. Lo peor ahora mismo es que el autor no elija una respuesta como válida de las múltiples que tiene !! :S:S

Comment: Hola. La cuenta la uso solo para temas clase, me explico, si tengo una duda importante y el profesor no puede atenderme la publico. Ahora que he podido ver bien las respuesta ya elegí la que considero que me ha ayudado más.

Comment: Bein Jonatan !! al final lo importante es que esto resulte útil ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo primero de todo deberías acostumbrarte a capitalizar las clases (Programa, no programa). Lo segundo es que no es muy buena práctica nombrar métodos igual que variables, induce a error.

Otra cosa que veo mal es que todos los métodos de la clase Coche están definidos para devolver un valor (char o double) pero no se le da ese uso; están funcionando como asignadores, deberías definir el método así:

```
public void setColor (String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Tampoco veo que definas un constructor para el objeto coche:

```
public Coche () {}
```

El valor double no se define como 1,4 sino -> 1.4d

De igual manera funciona con float (o Float si puede ser nulo) -> 2.36f

También defines el color a pelo, sin "" para el valor de la variable String.

```
package coches;

public class Coche {

    //Atributos
    private String color;
    private int matricula;
    private char tamaño;
    public String marca;
    private double version;

    public Coche () {}

    //Métodos
    public void setColor (String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    public void setMatricula (int matricula){ 
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public void setMarca (String marca){
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public void setVersion (double version){
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setTamaño(char tamaño) {
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (marca == null) return "sin marca";
        return this.marca;
    }  

}
```

Para el llamamiento te dejo las correcciones en base a la clase Coche que te adjunto.

```
package coches;

public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //Llamo a la clase coche
        Coche q = new Coche();

        //Ejecuto sus métodos
        q.setColor("azul");
        q.setMarca("Ford");
        q.setVersion(1.4d);
        q.setTamaño('a');
        q.setMatricula(1234);

        System.out.println(q.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Trata tambien de quitar loscaracteres especiales como la **Ñ**

Answer (score 5):

Tienes un problema de tipos.

Los parámetros que declaran las métodos de la clase coche son de tipo char (`public char color (char x)` ) y a la hora de llamar a estos métodos en la clase programa  `q.color(azul)`; pasas un string (que ni siquiera está correctamente entrecomillado).

Para que te funcione, según lo tienes, deberías llamar al método según lo has descrito, tal que así: `q.color('a')` pasando un char, y entrecomillado (sirven también las comillas dobles)

Unas recomendaciones para terminar:

1. Por convención, las clases en java siempre van con letra mayúscula, por lo que tus clases se deberían llamar **Coche** y **Programa**
2. Creo que lo que en realidad quieres es pasar parámetros de tipo String a tus métodos, de forma que puedas usar nombres más ajustados, además de utilizar setters y getters para los atributos de tu clase Coche.
3. Este tipo de problemas se palian utilizando un IDE que te avise de errores de tipo mientras escribes código. Puedes probar [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) o [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)

Para asignar valores a tus atributos, utiliza un setter, por ejemplo así:

```
public void setColor (String color){
    this.color = color
}
```

Y para leer el atributo, utiliza un getter, de esta forma:

```
   public String getColor (){
      return color;
   }
```

Ten en cuenta que, para que esto funcione correctamente, deberás tener un atributo color, declarado así:

```
private String color;
```

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar, tienes que acostumbrarte a nombrar las clase con la 1º letra en Mayuscula, evitar los caracteres especiales del español como: ñ, á, etc.
Ahora bien, tienes que definir bien que valores quieres dar a las propiedades del coche, porque según lo entiendo yo tienes que tener la clase Coche tal que:

```
public class Coche {

    // Atributos
    private String color;
    private int matricula;
    private String tamanio;
    private String marca;
    private double version;

    // Métodos:

    // Obtienes el color
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    // Cambias el valor.
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }
    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public String getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }
    public void setTamanio(String tamaño) {
        this.tamanio = tamaño;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public double getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(double version) {
        this.version = version;
    }   

}
```

Y tu clase Main, que es Programa, dar los valores, y luego verlos. Tu has intentado dar valores de palabras a números, eso no se puede, y los decimales están en versión Inlgesa, por tanto, se usa "." y no ",".
Total, el Main te queda:

```
public class Programa {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //Llamo a la clase coche
        Coche q;
        q = new Coche();
        // Das valores:
        q.setColor("Azul");
        q.setMarca("Ford");
        q.setVersion(1.4);
        q.setTamanio("Mediano");

        // Imprimes valores que has dado:
        System.out.println("Color: "+q.getColor());
        System.out.println("Marca: "+q.getMarca());
        System.out.println("Version: "+q.getVersion());
        System.out.println("Tamaño: "+q.getTamanio());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Yo usaria la Clase Color para el atributo color, int para matricula (o String)  y String para marca.
- Cuando pones `q.tamaño(mediano)`(ademas te falta el metodo tamaño) , ha de ser entre comillas tal que: `q.tamaño("mediano")` y lo mismo con marca.
- Los decimales de double se hacen con el "." (punto). Con coma parece que estas pasando dos parametros.
- Los metodos de la clase coche deberian retornar void y llamarse setColor y demas (para seguir un poco estandares de java)

```java
public class coche {

    //Atributos
    private Color color;
    private int matricula;
    private String tamaño;
    private String marca;
    private double version;

    //Métodos
    public void setColor (Color x){
        color = x;
    }
    public void setMatricula (int y){ 
        matricula = y;
    }
    public void setMarca (Stringz){
        marca = z;

    }
    public void setVersion (double a){
        version = a;

    }
    public void setTamaño(String a){
        version = a;

    }
}
```

```java
public class programa {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //Llamo a la clase coche
        coche q;
        q = new coche();
        //Ejecuto sus métodos
        q.setColor(Color.azul);
        q.setMarca("Ford");
        q.setVersion(1.4);
        q.setTamaño("mediano");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complemento un poco las respuestas que te han dado, ya que se basan en componentes Java Beans.

Te sugiero los siguientes enlaces que traen la definición y reglas para hacer estos componentes:

Esta es la documentación oficial:
[Writing Java Beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html)

Y por acá está la explicación en español:
[Introducción a los JavaBeans](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/applets/javaBeans/fundamento.htm)

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: ¿Java Beans?
Aquí no se ha comentado nada de Java Beans por ningún lado !! Es una respuesta que tiende a liar más la explicación de lo que se pregunta arriba. Si no se maneja el concepto de getter y settter.. mucho menos temas más avanzados como objetos serializados.